# How to use webstorm 11 to debug meteor 1.2 application with ecmascript package

Tags: debugging, meteor, webstorm, ecmascript-6

After recently updating my project to meteor 1.2 and including the new ecmascript package (to use ES2015 features), I realized that my server debug breakpoints will never run, no matter what I do.
After reading about different ES6 posts on meteor forums and [jetbrains](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/) , I tried setting up file watchers to create sourcemaps, but:

- meteor complains about the generated files(so you have to move them to special folders in order to keep going)
- It still doesn't work :(
- Setting up spy-js also didn't work (never tried before so maybe I did it wrong)

I could reproduce the problem with the basic TODOs application and debugging with default options.

Comment: Update: After updating to 11.0.3 this is generally solved again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed for now in EAP 11 builds.

Comment: Thanks, I already had updated and tried the fix, seems to be working ok again :)

Comment: broken again on 11.0.2 will wait for a new update to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-18074](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18074) for updates. Unfortunately I can't offer any workarounds:(